# No route matches [PUT] but I included "resources" in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm coding a blog that has two types of articles: "drafts" and "published".  I'm using the `aasm` gem for making the article transition from draft to published or viceverza. There are also three types of users: "regular readers", "editors" and "admins".

As users write articles, admins can evaluate whether to publish them or not. To accomplish this, admins have a view in which they can see both drafts and published articles.

The problem is that when I try to publish the articles I get the **No route matches [PUT] "/articles"** error, regardless I've added `resources :articles` in `routes.rb`.

The code I wrote is the following:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :categories
resources :articles do
   resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy, :show]
end 
devise_for :users
root 'welcome#index'
get '/dashboard', to: 'welcome#dashboard'
put '/articles/:id/publish', to: 'articles#publish'
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
...
def publish
     @article.publish! # Article transition from draft to published.
     redirect_to @article
end
...
```

**dashboard.html.erb**

```
...
<% @articles.each do |art| %>
<h1><%= link_to art.title, art, method: :get %> | id = <%= art.id %> | user_id = <%= art.user_id %></h1>
<div>
    <%= art.body %> - <%= link_to "Eliminar", art, method: :delete %>
    <% if art.may_publish? %>
        - <%= link_to "Publicar", '/articles/#{article.id}/publish' , method: :put %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
...
```

I can't see why I get this error if I included the article resource. If you need me to include more code don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What does $ rake routes show you?   Also you could have probably done `member do put :publish end` in your `resources :articles` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove your custom routes and put it into resources :articles like this :
routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  put 'publish', on: :member
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy, :show]
end
```

and you should use this in your view :

```
<%= button_to "Publicar", publish_article_path(article), method: :put %>
```

It will generate a form.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct, so try to reset the server and, by the way, restart the browser. It usually solves strange problems like this :) Let me know if it worked.